# Node Module.export and GET to display search results from form

Tags: node.js, forms, express, routes, pug

I'm really struggling with routing in express, specifically returning a module.export to a res.render function but I have tried every which combination of GET, POST, :q, results/, `req.params`, `req.body` and `req,query` and just cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to build a simple search box which renders the results. When I submit the form I can see the url req being posted in the dev tools ie, `q=lonsubmit=` and get come json data back but the results page never resolves. `docs` is never passed to the res.render. and is only available in the controller. How can I use it in the res.render('results')?

Is this because it is waiting for the results from the api? i can see the returned json if I console log. Why is the result page just hanging please?

app.js

```
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const resultsRouter = require('./routes/results');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', resultsRouter);
app.use('/', postRouter);
```

index.js

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  div.container-fluid
    div.row.justify-content-center
        p Find Your Dream Kruger Safari Package!
          form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0#searchBox(
                action='/results'
                method='GET'
                )
                  input.form-control.mr-sm-2(type='text', placeholder='City Code ie. LON, JHB, CPT', aria-label='Search', id='q' name='q' required autofocus)
                  button.btn.btn-success.my-2.my-sm-0(type='submit' id='submit' name="submit") Search
```

routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Safari Packages and Accommodation Bookings South Africa!'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

results.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Results  
  div.find test #{body}
  div.container
    div.row
      div.col-sm #{doc}
        p left col content
      div.col-sm
        tbody
          each doc in list
            tr
              td= doc.hotel.name
```

routes/results.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/results', (req, res) => {
  const q = req.query.q;
  const searchAmadeus = require('../controllers/amadeusControl.js');
  searchAmadeus.findNew(q, ( docs) => {
    res.render('results', {
      title: 'We Found Some Great Deals',
      list: docs,
    });

    console.log('Error  finding record :');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

amadeusControl.js

```
    module.exports = {
      findNew: function(q, docs) {

    const Amadeus = require('amadeus');
    const amadeus = new Amadeus({
      'clientId': process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID,
      'clientSecret': process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET,

    });
    console.log('q before amadeus', q);

    amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode: q,
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log('q inside function', q);
      const count = Object.keys(response).length;
      console.log(count);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.response); 
      console.log(error.response.request); 
      console.log(error.code); 
    });

  }};
```

routes/post.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/results', function(req, res) {
  const q = req.body.q;
  res.send(q);
  console.log('body', q);
  // res.send(q);
  // console.log(q);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Ok so Ive narrowed down the problem to using the `docs` var outside of the module.export for the controller. When I test using a test array I create I can see the output in my html. Why wont docs become accessible inside res.render?

`router.get('/results', (req, res, next) => {
  const cityCode = req.query.cityCode;
  const searchAmadeus = require('../controllers/amadeusControl.js');
  searchAmadeus.findNew(cityCode, (docs) => {
  });

  res.render('results', {
    title: 'We Found Some Great Deals',
    list: [5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], // integer works but need docs
  },
  );
},`

Comment: I also added a `return` to the controller but still no joy. Docs prints to the console but render doesn't pick it up.

`amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode: cityCode,
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log('q inside amadeus func', cityCode);
      docs = response.data;
      console.log('docs', docs);
      return docs;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.response); // => 
      console.log(error.response.request); 
      console.log(error.code); 
    });`